# Beaglebone black ( Debian Image 2014-05-14) goes to sleep after 10 minutes

Tags: ssh, power-management, beagleboneblack

As the title say it the board goes to sleep after 10 minutes. All I want is to SSH into the board (no keyboard/mouse or monitor attached). After googling for a good period of time all I found are some settings for X (Gui) I have also try the following command:

```
setterm -blank 0 -powersave off -append
```

It gives me the following error

```
setterm: cannot (un)set powersave mode: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

How can I fiddle or completely disable this power management. I am pretty sure is not a scheduled task or a process but rather the kernel itself and a setting I couldn't found.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure, but if your `/sys/power/state` file has a state, i.e. some string is returned, try `echo -n /sys/power/state` to make the file blank.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I left the instalation SD inserted into the board. It wasnt power management but rather the disto linux would install over and over again - therefore the approx 10 minutes interval. 
I am pretty sure the answer with the PM settings file is correct however it wasn't my case. 
Regards,
DAN